# If a function is integrable on [a, b]. does it have to be bounded?

Tags: integration, functions

What could be an counterexample?
Thanks!

Comment: Riemann or Lebesgue?

Comment: @Hamza: That function is not integrable.

Comment: I want to say $1/\sqrt x$ on $[0,1]$

Comment: Riemann and Lebesgue  require the function to be bounded!

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: It is possible for an unbounded function to be Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: @copper.hat you have not got the point!

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: What point have I not gotten? You have made a statement that is incorrect regarding boundedness of functions.

Comment: @copper.hat of course it is correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a Riemann integral, it must be bounded.

If it is the Lebesgue integral then $x \mapsto {1 \over \sqrt{x-a}}$ is an example of an unbounded integrable function.

Comment: If you want continuity of the function at $a$ and $b$, take$ f(x)=1/\sqrt {|x-(a+b)/2|}.$